# Loading a URL when dropdown option Changes in YUI

Tags: yui3

I am trying to load a URL when a drop down menu changes via YUI Change event. I just want to navigate to that URL.

I made a long search. But didn't got any way.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="http://example.com/home">Home</option>
    <option value="http://example.com/about">Abount</option>
</select>


Y.one("#dropdown").on("change", function() {
    //'this' points to dropdown node
    //so it's value is a value of selected option. Assume you keep new url there
    document.location.href = this.get('value'); 
});
```

Comment: is it working on IE 8.. ?? in my case it isn't working on  IE 8