# Load a link inside a SELECT tag in YUI

Tags: javascript, yui

I have a `SELECT` with many `option` items like this:

```
<select>
  <option data-link="http://www.foo.com">Link to Foo website</option>
  <option data-link="http://www.bar.com">Link to Bar website</option>
  ...
</select>
```

I'd need that when a user change SELECT value, it will be redirected to the corresponding website, which url is in `data-link` attribute.

*My constrain is that I can't use jQuery, I should use **YUI***.

Please, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not done much work with YUI, however, when working with it for a similar issue, I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490592/loading-a-url-when-dropdown-option-changes-in-yui) that seemed to work for me. The answer pertained to the code being like follows:

```
Y.one("#mySelect").on("change", function() {
   document.location.href = this.get('value'); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks. The only edit to my code is to replace `data-link` with `value` attribute

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to amend that part. Hope it helps.